# Top/left edges of screen, in Virtualbox, act like bottom/right edges

Tags: linux, windows-vista, virtualbox, debian, xorg

I have Virtualbox running on Windows Vista, and Debian running inside Virtualbox.  Everything's running great, for the most part.  Everything *looks* correct.

But when I'm in full-screen mode, the top edge seems to act (to the mouse) like it's the bottom edge, and the left edge seems to act like the right edge.  For example, if I click in the middle of the desktop and drag left, as if to select some icons, when I hit the very leftmost pixel of the screen, the selection (but not the mouse pointer) jumps to the far right edge of the screen).

For the left edge, it's not such a big deal, but not having the top edge is kind of annoying: it means I can't select things from the menu in my top panel by slamming the mouse against the top of the screen.

Anyone seen this before?  Is there some way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: +1, but why is this marked x11?

Comment: Because that's the software that's responsible for things like detecting what my mouse is clicking on.

Comment: Perhaps your X window manager is setup with multiple workspaces and you are jumping into the next workspace by putting your cursor on the edge?